# QgsVectorLayer no attribute setLayerName QGIS 3

Tags: python, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

What's the equivalent in QGIS3 of
`layer = QgsVectorLayer.setLayerName()`

Answer (score 2):

Its `.setName()`. Use it like this:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setName('my new layername')
```